# Python multiproceesing partial pool with multiple iterators

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to accomplish a task that involves doing it parallely using Multiprocessing pool in Python. Basically there are some static parameters for a function and a bunch of variable parameters for different hyperparamters. For eg.

```
def simulate(static1, static2, iter1, iter2):
    #do some math in for loop
    return output
```

Now the thing is nth component in iter2 comes only with nth component of iter1. Like say

```
iter1 = [1,2,3,4]
iter2 = [x,y,z,w]
```

So during iteration (1,x),(2,y) etc. should be there as the parameters and in the end I expect to get 4 different outputs. SO I am trying to implement

```
partial_function = partial(simulate, static1 = s1, static2 = s2)
output = pool.map(partial, (iter1, iter2))
```

I am stuck at how to use multiple iters given that python returns TypeError mentioning `simulate() missing 1 positional argument`. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here. Where are you using a pool? Are you just asking how to do `pool.starmap(myfunc, zip(iter1, iter2))`? Possibly `pool.starmap(simulate, zip(itertools.repeat(static1), itertools.repeat(static2), iter1, iter2))`?

Comment: `args = (zip(iter1, iter2))`

Comment: @ShadowRanger I have edited the question. Hope it expresses my question better.